# Problems with Rails.cache: Exception while duping an array on Rails: TypeError (can't modify frozen object)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

The following code generates a **TypeError (can't modify frozen object)**. But all we're doing is duping the cached item. Anyone know why? We're on Rails 3.0.6 and Ruby 1.8.7. Thanks!

We also tried using **clone** and then unfreezing the resulting object, but that also generated the same exception.

**pack** is not defined anywhere else.

```
    cached_pack = Rails.cache.fetch( 'packs/' + pack_id, {:expires_in => 10.days} ) do
        Rails.logger.info '+++ Cache miss: '
        Pack.find pack_id
    end         

    pack = cached_pack.dup
```

Comment: what ruby version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade to Rails 3.1 or higher since dup is introduced then.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDNR** version: use `clone`, not `dup`.

There are two main differences between `clone` and `dup`:

- `dup` doesn't clones singleton methods while `clone` does;
- the `clone` of a frozen object is also frozen (whereas a `dup` of a frozen object isn't).

This is how it works in Rails 3.1+. In your case, you should use `clone` because `ActiveRecord#dup` was introduced in Rails 3.1 and hence you are likely calling `Kernel#dup`.

**UPD** BTW, `Rails.cache` silently freezes the objects, being put in cache (at least in Rails < 3.2). To avoid such behaviour, one can put objects’ dups rather than objects themselves to cache with:

```
cached_resource.cache.write( \
  key, object.dup, :expires_in => cached_resource.generate_ttl \
)
```

Comment: thanks! but if we clone the frozen object, won't we run into the same error?

Comment: If we clone the frozen object, we’ll get the frozen copy. That’s it. To my pity I can’t check it right now (no env here,) but it should be OK.

Comment: i don't think this works because the cloned copy will generate the same error since it is also frozen.

Comment: `clone` itself will definitely work. If you want to modify the `pack` in the future, you should reformulate a question, since an error occurs somewhere in further code.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with assigning value `pack = cached_pack.dup` itself. Nothing may prevent you of duping an object and assigning the result to fresh var. I have updated an answer, maybe it will help. Sorry, that’s all I can suggest for now. Try to debug (or at least log) every line of your code to determine where exactly an exception is raised.

Comment: right, the problem is we're on 3.0.6, and dup doesn't exist until 3.1. we need a way to clone something without making it frozen. we tried cloning then unfreezing, but even calling clone on the object generates the same error.

Comment: As an ugly hack I would suggest you to serialize and immediately unserialize your `cached_pack` inplace instead of cloning it.